# Variable not being recognized after "read"

Tags: solaris, ksh

-- Edit : Resolved. See answer.

Background: 
I'm writing a shell that will perform some extra actions required on our system when someone resizes a database.
The shell is written in ksh (requirement), the OS is Solaris 5.10 .
The problem is with one of the checks, which verifies there's enough free space on the underlying OS.

Problem: 
The check reads the df -k line for root, which is what I check in this step, and prints it to a file. I then "read" the contents into variables which I use in calculations. 
Unfortunately, when I try to run an arithmetic operation on one of the variables, I get an error indicating it is null. And a debug output line I've placed after that line verifies that it is null... It lost it's value...

I've tried every method of doing this I could find online, they work when I run it manually, but not inside the shell file. 
(* The file does have #!/usr/bin/ksh)

Code:

```
df -k | grep "rpool/ROOT" > dftest.out  
RPOOL_NAME=""; declare -i TOTAL_SIZE=0; USED_SPACE=0; AVAILABLE_SPACE=0; AVAILABLE_PERCENT=0; RSIGN=""  
read RPOOL_NAME TOTAL_SIZE USED_SPACE AVAILABLE_SPACE AVAILABLE_PERCENT RSIGN < dftest.out  
\rm dftest.out  
echo $RPOOL_NAME $TOTAL_SIZE $USED_SPACE $AVAILABLE_SPACE $AVAILABLE_PERCENT $RSIGN  
((TOTAL_SIZE=$TOTAL_SIZE/1024))
```

This is the result:
DBResize.sh[11]: TOTAL_SIZE=/1024: syntax error

I'm pulling hairs at this point, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you have to add `$` to `(())` constructs to do math, so it should be `TOTAL_SIZE=$(($TOTAL_SIZE/1024))`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Both are valid ways of variable assigning and arithmetic operation.

Comment: Can you shouw the contents of `dftest.out` ?
You can start debugging by removing the line with `declare -i`, with `set -x` or with `echo "test 8 2 6 75% =" > dftest.out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted cannot produce the output you posted. Most obviously, the error is signalled at line 11 but you posted fewer than 11 lines of code. The previous lines may matter. Always post [complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you ask for help.

More concretely, the `declare` command doesn't exist in ksh, it's a bash thing. You can achieve the same result with `typeset` (`declare` is a bash equivalent to `typeset`, but not all options are the same). Either you're executing this script with bash, or there's another error message about `declare`, or you've defined some additional commands including `declare` which may change the behavior of this code.

None of this should have an impact on the particular problem that you're posting about, however. The variables created by `read` remain assigned until the end of the subshell, i.e. until the code hits a `)`, the end of a pipe (left-hand side of the pipe only in ksh), etc.

About the use of `declare` or `typeset`, note that you're only declaring `TOTAL_SIZE` as an integer. For the other variables, you're just assigning a value which happens to consist exclusively of digits. It doesn't matter for the code you posted, but it's probably not what you meant.

One thing that may be happening is that `grep` matches nothing, and therefore `read` reads an empty line. You should check for errors. Use `set -e` in scripts to exit at the first error. (There are cases where `set -e` doesn't catch errors, but it's a good start.)

Another thing that may be happening is that `df` is splitting its output onto multiple lines because the first column containing the filesystem name is too large. To prevent this splitting, pass the option `-P`.

Using a temporary file is fragile: the code may be executed in a read-only directory, another process may want to access the same file at the same time... Here a temporary file is useless. Just pipe directly into `read`. In ksh (unlike most other sh variants including bash), the right-hand side of a pipe runs in the main shell, so assignments to variables in the right-hand side of a pipe remain available in the following commands.

It doesn't matter in this particular script, but you can use a variable without `$` in an arithmetic expression. Using `$` substitutes a string which can have confusing results, e.g. `a='1+2'; $((a*3))` expands to `7`. Not using `$` uses the numerical value (in ksh, `a='1+2'; $((a*3))` expands to `9`; in some sh implementations you get an error because `a`'s value is not numeric).

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
set -e
typeset -i TOTAL_SIZE=0 USED_SPACE=0 AVAILABLE_SPACE=0 AVAILABLE_PERCENT=0
df -Pk | grep "rpool/ROOT" | read RPOOL_NAME TOTAL_SIZE USED_SPACE AVAILABLE_SPACE AVAILABLE_PERCENT RSIGN  
echo $RPOOL_NAME $TOTAL_SIZE $USED_SPACE $AVAILABLE_SPACE $AVAILABLE_PERCENT $RSIGN  
((TOTAL_SIZE=TOTAL_SIZE/1024))
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange...when I get rid of your "declare" line, your original code seems to work perfectly well (at least with ksh on Linux)

The code :

```
#!/bin/ksh

df -k | grep "/home" > dftest.out
read RPOOL_NAME TOTAL_SIZE USED_SPACE AVAILABLE_SPACE AVAILABLE_PERCENT RSIGN < dftest.out
\rm dftest.out

echo $RPOOL_NAME $TOTAL_SIZE $USED_SPACE $AVAILABLE_SPACE $AVAILABLE_PERCENT $RSIGN
((TOTAL_SIZE=$TOTAL_SIZE/1024))
print $TOTAL_SIZE
```

The result :

```
32962416 5732492 25552588 19% /home
5598
```

Which are the value a simple df -k is returning. The variables seem to last.

Answer (score -1):

For those interested, I have figured out that it is not possible to use "read" the way I was using it.
The variable values assigned by "read" simply "do not last".
To remedy this, I have applied the less than ideal solution of using the standard "while read" format, and inside the loop, echo selected variables into a variable file.
Once said file was created, I just "loaded" it.

(pseudo code:)

```
LOOP START
echo "VAR_A="$VAR_A"; VAR_B="$VAR_B";" > somefile.out
LOOP END
. somefile.out
```

Comment: Your analysis is wrong: it is possible to use `read` the way you were using it. What made your code work must have been some other change.

Comment: As pointed out originally, when I tried it manually it did work. It just didn't work as part of the full code. I suppose it is possible there is something, somewhere else, that is the problem, but that merely means that the above solution is what worked with whatever other component was causing it. Maybe the formatting on the df -k output just happened to mess it up on that server.